# Gridview Add/delete rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How can I ADD, Delete and Edit multiple rows "containing textboxes" to Gridview

Without inserting to DB

I tried

```
Gridview1.rows.add(datarow)
```

And for delete

```
Gridview1.rows.remove(datarow)
```

but without detecting selected row

Comment: How do you construct your datarow ? can you show more code ?

Comment: You can bind to a `DataTable` without a database. I would not reccommend manipulating grid rows directly, just manipulate the data it is bound to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach in code below for this. In the `addRow` method shown, a new grid row is inserted. The logic is that we need to re-bind the grid to a new data source that contains the original rows plus a new empty row. You can use a similar approach for delete ( create a new data source with deleted rows  excluded and then rebind the grid).

When deleting use the method `deleteRow`. I have assumed that you have a check box control with an id of `chkDelete` in the grid row, which when checked would mean the row needs to be deleted. You can delete multiple rows at the same time using the method of `deleteRow`.

If you use the below two methods for adding a row and deleting row(s) then automatically your edited text boxes would have their new values retained always i.e. `editing would then be automatically taken care of`.

**Assumptions made** : *Also, I have assumed that there are 3 text boxes in grid row in addition to a check box.* Because there are 3 textboxes, so the DataTable being created in methods below should contain 3 columns for these 3 textboxes and these columns should be of string type.

**Add a Row**

```
protected void addRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    //add code to create columns for this data table
    //only create columns for textbox data
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
    DataRow dr = null;

    //build a data source of existing rows
    foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grid1.Rows)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        //set only text box values in new data source
        //so checkbox column for row selection will be ignored
        TextBox txtColumn1 = gridRow.FindControl("txtColumn1") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtColumn2 = gridRow.FindControl("txtColumn2") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtColumn3 = gridRow.FindControl("txtColumn3") as TextBox;

        dr[0] = txtColumn1.Text;
        dr[1] = txtColumn2.Text;
        dr[2] = txtColumn3.Text;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
    }

    //create the row in data sourec for the new grid row
    dr = dt.NewRow(); 
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //bind the grid view, which will now show you the new added row in addition to original rows
    grd.DataSource = dt; 
    grd.DataBind();
}
```

**Delete Row(s)**

```
protected void deleteRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    //add code to create column for this data table
    //only set column for textbox columns
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));

    //build a data source of existing rows
    foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grid1.Rows)
    {
        //get whether the checkbox for deleting row is checked or not
        CheckBox chkDelete = gridRow.FindControl("chkDelete") as CheckBox;
        //do not add original row if it was checked to be deleted
        if(!chkDelete.Checked)
         {
           dr = dt.NewRow();

           //set only text box values in new data source
           //so checkbox column for row selection will be ignored
           TextBox txtColumn1 = gridRow.FindControl("txtColumn1") as TextBox;
           TextBox txtColumn2 = gridRow.FindControl("txtColumn2") as TextBox;
           TextBox txtColumn3 = gridRow.FindControl("txtColumn3") as TextBox;

           dr[0] = txtColumn1.Text;
           dr[1] = txtColumn2.Text;
           dr[2] = txtColumn3.Text;

           dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
       }
    }

    //bind the grid view, which will now NOT have the deleted rows
    grd.DataSource = dt; 
    grd.DataBind();
}
```